# Github Action: [!] Error: Cannot find module 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

In my package.json there are `rollup` and `rollup-plugin-commonjs`
but inside github actions it could not find those packages!

If I do not add rollup in global package installation step of github-action it shows that `rollup` is not found. But after adding both rollup and rollup-plugin-commonjs I get `[!] Error: Cannot find module 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'`

this is my workflow file:

```
name: Github Action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - fix/auto-test

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04


    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Bootstrap app on Ubuntu
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '11.x.x'
      - name: Install global packages
        run: npm install -g prisma rollup rollup-plugin-commonjs

      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

      - name: Cache Project dependencies test
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install project deps
        if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn

      - name: Run docker
        run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.prisma.yml up --build -d

      - name: Sleep
        uses: jakejarvis/wait-action@master
        with:
          time: '30s'

      - name: Reset the database for safety
        run: yarn reset:backend

      - name: Deploy
        run: yarn deploy:backend

      - name: Build this great app
        run: yarn build

      - name: start app and worker concurrently and create some instances
        run: |
          yarn start &
          yarn start:worker &
          xvfb-run --auto-servernum yarn test:minimal:runner
```

Comment: which step is the one that exits non-zero?

Comment: Built this great app

Comment: what's your build script defined as in your package.json file

Comment: @Ashik Were you able to get this to work? I am having similar issues.